# Run a SSRS report on a form in Dynamics CRM2011

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to create a report for a specific record and run it on the form of a particular record. Here in the following I have so for work done.

```
SELECT 
           new_contacttitlename AS 'Title',
           new_casenumber AS 'casenumber',
           new_contactfirstname as 'FirstName',
 FROM
     FilteredIncident AS CRMAF_FilteredIncident
```

But the problem is that the report runs on a form but it brings data for other records. I've tested it for many records. But the problem is not sorted out :(

Please guide me with your kind suggestions and ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you shed some more light the following points

- On which entity record are you trying to pull the records, based on your query you would be opening up the report from a Case record, is that correct?
- How are you accessing the report? from CRM or BIDS?

If you are previewing the report from BIDS then you will see all the records being pulled in the report. If this is the case then I would suggest you to first update the rdl file in CRM and try running it from case entity form.

Comment: Yes, @Piyush am trying for case entity. Created in BIDS, run and uploaded in CRM.

Comment: hmm.. that's odd, can you delete the report in CRM and recreate it. Also, try refreshing the fields in BIDS for your dataset

Comment: CRM can be quite moody regarding the prefiltering functionality, as piyush points out. Many problems can be solved only by removing the report and upload it again.

Answer (score 1):

If its an easy report, then sugest you to use Report Wizard.

Otherwise you have to pass the record as parameter and use where statement.

Im not sure but have you tried to run it on the Form it should run in the record context and show only that.

Please let me know of result

Comment: Yes, I've tried for numerous records. It display records but not for that record.

Comment: Then add a where condition with parameter

Comment: hmmm. . .what should be in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
select CRMAF_FilteredIncident.FilteredIncidentid,
       new_contacttitlename AS 'Title',
       new_casenumber AS 'casenumber',
       new_contactfirstname as 'FirstName',
FROM
 FilteredIncident AS CRMAF_FilteredIncident
```

And when you add this report make sure you select that you can run it from a single record.